# How to check whether target is removed from the element or not in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$(".dropdown-toggle").click(function(event) {
  var target = $(event.target);
  if (target.is(this)) {
    $(this).find(".caret").toggleClass("customcaret");
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="dropdown-toggle">
  <div class="caret"></div>
</div>
```

This code is working properly when I click on `.dropdown-toggle`, `.caret` is being affected (class is being changed on `.dropdown-toggle`).

But how I can toggle `.customcaret` class from `.caret` on clicking outside the `.dropdown-toggle`.

Comment: you can read stackoverflow docs for proper formatting can you pls add the css and html to throw more light on your issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make changes in your script like :

**HTML**

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown-toggle" style="float:left;">
  <div class="caret">Click Here</div>
</div>
```

**SCRIPT**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".dropdown-toggle").click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    $(this).find(".caret").addClass("customcaret");
  });
  $("body").click(function() {
    if($(".dropdown-toggle").find(".caret").hasClass("customcaret")){
      $(".dropdown-toggle").find(".caret").removeClass("customcaret");
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make a click event on the body that removes the class 'customcaret' from your element.

Comment: Peter answer is good; you only remove the class not toggle it